# Ubuntu 12.10 - Session.log filling hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, disk-space, event-log

Here's a goofy problem.

On my Ubuntu computer the session.log and session.log.old files have been continually filling up the hard drive. I've got a 80gb partition for the OS and these logs have gotten as big as 74gb.

Initially started under 10.04 Wubi. Thought it was the Wubi install and since i dont keep my on my ubuntu box (file server) i re-installed as a full install of 10.04. Problem came back a week later.

Figured maybe a bug in 10.04? Bit the bullet and upgraded to 12.10 w/GNome (hate unity) and it has happened again.

Server has been fine for years then this started in last month. I only have X-Chat installed, that's about it other than stock. I mainly remote into it via VNC. THanks!

Comment: Please post the output of `cat <the log file> | head -n5` so I have an idea who created the log.

Comment: /etc/gdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:admin being added to access control list
localuser:admin being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0

Comment: So it did it again.. once again the session.log has filled up the entire drive. Absolutely nothing running that's out of place. Just a few browsers and email (thunderbird).. and X-Chat. Not even a VNC session. What the heck is causing this? I ran the cat above and thats what it spit out. THanks!

Comment: It looks to me like you can delete it.

Comment: well obviously you can delete it.. but doesn't really stop the problem as it just happens again (and again.. and again). When the file system fills up VNC crashes and a lot of things stop working so i have to manually delete the file from the console which sucks. It also doesn't seem to happen incrementally.. ie it will fill up the hard drive almost instantaneously when whatever bug hits.. hits. Has to be something recent causing this.